# PostgreSQL fetching (sometimes) too slow

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a few million rows, where I am constantly inserting new data and also fetching.

The structure is:

```
                ('orig_city', 'INTEGER NOT NULL'),
                ('dest_city', 'INTEGER NOT NULL'),
                ('dep_date', 'DATE NOT NULL'),
                ('orig_city_code', 'TEXT NOT NULL'),
                ('dest_city_code', 'TEXT NOT NULL'),
                ('trip_id', 'TEXT'),
                ('agent', 'TEXT'),
                ('source', 'TEXT'),
                ('price', 'INTEGER'),
                ('deep_link', 'TEXT'),
                ('ts', 'TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
                ('PRIMARY KEY', '(trip_id, agent, source)')
```

with `idx_trips_201809` = `'orig_city, dest_city, dep_date'`

It usually works good enough, but I realized that from time to time there are some `SELECT` queries that are far too slow.

I saw that a couple of times it took even more than 40 seconds. Unfortunately, I was not able to replicate those for the `EXPLAIN` command.

All commands are executed through python. Here is an example.

Query:

```
sql_query = """SELECT * FROM trips_201809 WHERE (orig_city = %s OR dest_city = %s) AND dep_date = %s"""
vals = (91, 279, 2018-09-21)

cur.execute(sql_query, vals)
fetched = cur.fetchall()
```

where 2018-09-21 is a `datetime.date` object.

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` shows:

```
('Bitmap Heap Scan on trips_201809  (cost=45576.77..50231.46 rows=2430 width=769) (actual time=1055.970..5993.580 rows=2597 loops=1)',)
("  Recheck Cond: (((orig_city = 91) AND (dep_date = '2018-09-21'::date)) OR ((dest_city = 279) AND (dep_date = '2018-09-21'::date)))",)
('  Heap Blocks: exact=1199',)
('  ->  BitmapOr  (cost=45576.77..45576.77 rows=2438 width=0) (actual time=1038.635..1038.635 rows=0 loops=1)',)
('        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_trips_201809  (cost=0.00..593.63 rows=1824 width=0) (actual time=22.119..22.119 rows=1605 loops=1)',)
("              Index Cond: ((orig_city = 91) AND (dep_date = '2018-09-21'::date))",)
('        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_trips_201809  (cost=0.00..44982.90 rows=614 width=0) (actual time=1016.514..1016.514 rows=1004 loops=1)',)
("              Index Cond: ((dest_city = 279) AND (dep_date = '2018-09-21'::date))",)
('Planning time: 0.927 ms',)
('Execution time: 5994.242 ms',)
```

-

```
('Bitmap Heap Scan on trips_201809  (cost=45576.77..50231.46 rows=2430 width=769) (actual time=2923.961..2984.264 rows=2597 loops=1)',)
("  Recheck Cond: (((orig_city = 91) AND (dep_date = '2018-09-21'::date)) OR ((dest_city = 279) AND (dep_date = '2018-09-21'::date)))",)
('  Heap Blocks: exact=1199',)
('  ->  BitmapOr  (cost=45576.77..45576.77 rows=2438 width=0) (actual time=2923.785..2923.785 rows=0 loops=1)',)
('        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_trips_201809  (cost=0.00..593.63 rows=1824 width=0) (actual time=1.818..1.818 rows=1605 loops=1)',)
("              Index Cond: ((orig_city = 91) AND (dep_date = '2018-09-21'::date))",)
('        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_trips_201809  (cost=0.00..44982.90 rows=614 width=0) (actual time=2921.966..2921.966 rows=1004 loops=1)',)
("              Index Cond: ((dest_city = 279) AND (dep_date = '2018-09-21'::date))",)
('Planning time: 0.731 ms',)
('Execution time: 2984.482 ms',)
```

-

```
('Bitmap Heap Scan on trips_201809  (cost=45576.77..50231.46 rows=2430 width=769) (actual time=231.375..233.616 rows=2598 loops=1)',)
("  Recheck Cond: (((orig_city = 91) AND (dep_date = '2018-09-21'::date)) OR ((dest_city = 279) AND (dep_date = '2018-09-21'::date)))",)
('  Heap Blocks: exact=1200',)
('  ->  BitmapOr  (cost=45576.77..45576.77 rows=2438 width=0) (actual time=231.222..231.222 rows=0 loops=1)',)
('        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_trips_201809  (cost=0.00..593.63 rows=1824 width=0) (actual time=1.781..1.781 rows=1605 loops=1)',)
("              Index Cond: ((orig_city = 91) AND (dep_date = '2018-09-21'::date))",)
('        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_trips_201809  (cost=0.00..44982.90 rows=614 width=0) (actual time=229.440..229.440 rows=1005 loops=1)',)
("              Index Cond: ((dest_city = 279) AND (dep_date = '2018-09-21'::date))",)
('Planning time: 0.665 ms',)
('Execution time: 233.778 ms',)
```

I can see that the issue is in the execution, not in the planning. But I am not able to find out what exactly is making it slow.

Why are the executions times so variable?

And how could I avoid that sometimes it takes so long?

---

Additional information, as requested in the comments.

Selectivity for a typical query:

- `dep_date`: 3%
- `orig_city`: between 0.1 - 1%
- `dest_city`: between 0.1 - 1%

The index the plans mentions is the one I explained at the beginning of the question. I edited that to make it more clear

In this table, which is for the moment the critical one, around 3% of the rows will be selected for a specific date. However, I have other similar tables where that % would be also between a 0.1 - 1%.

---

**Edit**

Adding an index `dep_date, orig_city, dest_city` has improved the speed of fetching. However, it is still not as fast as I had expected. Any additional suggestion are more than welcome.

```
('Bitmap Heap Scan on trips_201809  (cost=1326.19..13315.79 rows=6432 width=772) (actual time=553.464..1273.092 rows=6577 loops=1)',)
("  Recheck Cond: (((dep_date = '2018-09-21'::date) AND (orig_city = 353)) OR ((dep_date = '2018-09-21'::date) AND (dest_city = 106)))",)
('  Heap Blocks: exact=2010',)
('  ->  BitmapOr  (actual time=552.436..552.436 rows=0 loops=1)',)
('        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_trp_201809  (cost=0.00..27.56 rows=2739 width=0) (actual time=0.300..0.300 rows=2136 loops=1)',)
("              Index Cond: ((dep_date = '2018-09-21'::date) AND (orig_city = 353))",)
('        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_trp_201809  (cost=0.00..1297.99 rows=3771 width=0) (actual time=552.134..552.134 rows=4926 loops=1)',)
("              Index Cond: ((dep_date = '2018-09-21'::date) AND (dest_city = 106))",)
('Planning time: 100.031 ms',)
('Execution time: 1273.483 ms',)
```

Comment: First of all your searching condition `(orig_city = x OR dest_city = y) AND dep_date = z` is based on three columns. Can you provide the selectivity of each column for "typical" queries? **Selectivity** is the percentage of rows each separate column condition selects compared to the total number or rows in the table.

Comment: Also, please provide the definition of the index `idx_trips_201809`. This is the index the plan mentions.

Comment: I cannot answer the question. However, how many rows may be in the table for one departure date? Probably only few. And in your query you only want to see rows for one particular departure date. So you should have an index starting with this. The other two columns have `OR` and there cannot be one index starting with one as well as with the other, so these columns may appear in the index, but it should *start* with the departure date. So you should at least have an index on `dep_date`, and even better would be an index on `dep_date, orig_city, dest_city`.

Comment: Thinking the same thing. The index columns should be flipped. It's scanning the index twice and then oring it (BitmapOr). It would be probably much faster if it started by the date.

Comment: Thanks @TheImpaler , I have edited the question to provide the selectivity info.

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenKettner , you will find the details in the edited question. Do you both mean that just switching my index from `orig_city, dest_city, dep_date` to `dep_date, orig_city, dest_city` would suffice?

Comment: Yes. For this query at least. It may make sense to have both indexes, because other queries may have other where clauses that need the original index.

Comment: Danke! I will give it a try and write the outcome here.

Comment: I have added the index as suggested and it makes it faster. However, sometimes it still takes more than 1 second. I updated the question with the info. Anyway, feel free to post a reply so I mark the answer as accepted.